# db.sadd is not a function?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I'm trying to run some Nodejs examples from the Express examples GitHub at [this link](https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/examples/search).

For this linked example, I ran `npm update` and ensured Redis is in the root `package.json` is `"redis": "^4.6.7"`, however am receiving the following error about `sadd` function not present.  I searched Redis [GitHub](https://github.com/redis/redis) for `sadd` and did not see the function definition.

Does anyone know what is going on or how to debug this further?

```
$ node index.js
/home/vboxuser/src/nr/express/examples/search/index.js:28
db.sadd('ferret', 'tobi');
   ^

TypeError: db.sadd is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vboxuser/src/nr/express/examples/search/index.js:28:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is incorrect. The correct function name is `.sAdd` or `.SADD`. I usually go with `.sAdd` as all caps feels weird in code. I would heartily encourage you to send them a PR.

If you run into other issues like this, you can find the pretty much everything in or off of the [Node Redis README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis).

Comment: I went ahead and sent in a PR.

Comment: There are deeper issues with this example. I wouldn't recommend using it. I have an [Express and Redis example](https://github.com/guyroyse/beyond-the-cache) for a workshop that I do that could be helpful.